# practice with box plot structure

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

today finally i want to customize to box plot structure ,let us consider following problem
[image]

so we have  $800$ data,rom which we can conclude that median is $118$ approximately,first quartile is $114$ and  third one is $126$,interquartile is $126-114=12$,i am right yes in this part?minimum value is  $105$ and maximum value is $146$,now what about second question?if $80$ percentile is  $130$,it means that $80$ percent of data fall below $130$ right?or $20$ percent is between $130$ and $146$,we can count that $16$ data  corresponds  $20$ percent of data,so between $126$  and  $130$ corresponds $5$ percent?here number if we count is  $3$ number,but are they asking percents or numbers?
EDITED:
i have not counted  $800$, $20$ percent between  $130$ and $146$ means that $160$ number fall between this interval,so  between $126$ and $130$ would it be  $160/16*3=30$? about range it is maximum minus smallest or $146-105=41$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the median (the central line) is closer to $118$ than $116$, but your other values seem reasonable.

If the [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28statistics%29) is a single length then it is $146-105=41$, as in your edit.

On (b) I would have said that if 5% of the measurements (the difference between 80% and 75%) are between $126$ and $130$, then this corresponds to $800 \times 0.05 = 40$ actual measurements.

Comment: does it includes  inclusive part?i mean when both number is  also included or it is not considered here?yes answer is $40$

Comment: @dato: A good question to which there is not a good answer.  The median is somewhere between ranked observations 400 and 401; the upper quartile is somewhere between ranked observations 600 and 601; the 80th percentile is somewhere between ranked observations 640 and 641. So 40 observations is a reasonable solution. But strictly speaking in Tukey's specification,  hinges are used on a boxplot rather than quartiles, though life is too short to bother with the difference.